# Creating a Chrome extension that traverses multiple open Google docs files

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-docs

So my example premise is this:

I've got four Google (docs) Sheets open in one window as (4) tabs and a separate window for work. I would like to create a Chrome extension that does the following:

On a shortcut key press I would get the first column of the first Sheet into my clipboard, thus being able to paste it in my working window. On the next key press, I'd get the first column from the second Sheet, and on the next the first from the third etc. Then it should loop back to the first Sheet to get the second column, then the second column from the second sheet etc. ...

My main question is is this possible with just a Chrome extension?

Also would gladly hear some pointers (I've got a decent background in JavaScript), never done a Chrome extension before, though just started reading the documentation from Google.

Comment: Getting data from a google doc is probably too much work. Try to export the doc as html if you can, then use js.

Comment: No it isn't difficult.  Google has a lot of backend apis.  A little while ago I found some little urls that would return a google sheet as a pure text file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/DOCUMENT_ID_HERE/export?format=csv&gid=0&single=true&output=csv  unlike most of the other url structures this can return a document without it being publicly published, only if a user with access to the document is logged on(i think).

Comment: @MarcGuiselin, thanks mate, I'll look into it!

Comment: have you had any luck?

Comment: @MarcGuiselin, Thanks for the interest :-) I actually came up with a completely different solution as I'll (hopefully) be able to use AJAX for the same sort of job in the future. Currently I just macro'd the hell out of everything (with Keyboard Maestro).

Comment: Great! Happy you got that working.